# What minimum dimension of the Hilbert Space is required so that the commutation relations are satisfied?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, wavefunction, commutator

What should be the minimum dimension of the Hilbert space so that the commutation relation
$[\hat{x},\hat{p}] = i\hbar$ is satisfied?

What is the maximum dimension so that it is satisfied?

Will these values remain same for other commutation relations like:

$$[L_x,L_y]=i\hbar L_z$$
$$[L_y,L_z]=i\hbar L_x$$
$$[L_z, L_x]=i\hbar L_y$$

etc.?
$$$$

Comment: 1. Why do you think there's such a thing as a "maximum" dimension? If you've got a space $H$ with the given commutation relations, $H^{\otimes n}$ and other tensor product also form a representation of the same commutation relations. 2. You obviously seem to know that there's some aspect of the relations that says something about dimensionality, but you've given us absolutely no indication what you've tried or what you already know. Why not?

Comment: It might be good to look up the dimensionality of the first few representations of simple Lie algebras.

Answer (score 3):

the fundamental commutation relation $[\hat{x}, \hat{p}] = i\hbar$ cannot be satisfied in any finite-dimensional Hilbert space, as in such a space we would always be able to write $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ (if they are well-defined) as finite matrices $X_{n,m} = \langle n | \hat{x} | m \rangle$, $P_{n,m} = \langle n | \hat{p} | m \rangle$ but for any pair of finite matrices $A, B$
$$ {\rm tr}\left([A , B]\right) = 0$$
because the trace is cyclic (i.e. ${\rm tr}(AB) = {\rm tr}(BA)$. So clearly it cannot be constant.

The commutation relations for $L_i$ can be maintained for any dimension, but sometimes they will be maintained trivially. So for a Hilbery space of dimension $1$, they will be maintained because all of them are identically zero.

There is no upper constraint on the dimension of Hilbert space, above which we have to invalidate these commutation relations.